# Taxonomy menu containing CCK field as child/ sub menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, cck, taxonomy

Hello I have developed few sites using Drupal and this is the first time I getting a requirement from a client.

The site is about a vehicle store. so when creating a vehicle there is Name, Make, Model, Year, Mileage etc... as fields to be filled The "Make" field is a dropdown list which the field type is "Term reference" and used a taxonomy vocabulary "Vehicle make" The "Model" is just a text field where it could be custom typed

All what I want is a Menu : having The "Make" as the Parent/main menu Item and to list all the model which comes under the particular make.

something like

Toyota

- Prius
- Corollo
- Super GL

Honda

- Civic
- Insight

could I do this using a view ?

It's pretty urgent and would appreciate even a clue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are few modules out there which offer you similar features. Try with taxonomy block and/or taxonomy menu bloc.